# asp .net Scan folder once a day

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web application in asp .net. I want to scan a folder once a day in order to find if new files are imported and do some processing. Where do you suggest me to put this code?. Do i have to make a service?.

Comment: Create a batch-file or executable that does the scan and processing and put it in the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 4):

Do you own the server? Then you can make a C# console application and just add the exe to your scheduled task list.

If you don't own the server and have no way to schedule tasks then make just an aspx file that do the job... You call your aspx files URL once a day.

Use some online scheduler system, like this one http://http.sh/ so they will call your aspx batch-page once a day.

Comment: Depends on the server version. If it is any of the last O/S use this tutorial http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx#BKMK_cmd    if the windows version is anything below 7, then try this tutorial:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569/en-us

Comment: I do not own the server. But if i put the code in an aspx file , then the code is going to execute when a user start a new session , right ?

Comment: Thus if there is no visitor in a day then is not going to scan it?

Comment: No, just make an ASPX page, for exaple "scan-folder.aspx" you must invoke this page using your browser. If the page works and the scan is performed successfully, then the next step is to make some automated process invoke "scan-folder.aspx".

Comment: So you recomend me to call this page my self once a day?.

Comment: Not you, use an automated http scheduler... like the one I just gave you http://http.sh

Comment: Hm but is it a proper solution ?

Comment: Of course there can be better ways to do it, it's always better if you do server tasks on the server side, like scheduling. But in your scenario, when you don't have admin rights nor remote access to configure the server, it's the simplest yet flexible workaround. Once you get a dedicated hosting environment, (e.g. you move to Amazon AWS) then the machine is yours and you can go for the right way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) Class

This class listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program. 
        if(args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Define the event handlers. 
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to call this code from outside a service would make sence, otherwise you can just use it in your application. It sounds for me like a synchronizing issue between computers, if its the case you can find a lot of solutions for this, some of them are pretty good, take a look [here](http://ehacker.com/372175/free-ways-to-synchronize-folders-between-computers).

Another Idea would be to use Version control (svn) for the files you would like to check, this will enable you to discover changed files from the command line, not sure this helps but its worth to be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I stumble on this problem quite often. If you ask me I would say that a 'poor mans' solution is to create some timer on application start and do work via the timers event. I just don't like the idea of Global having this kind of state.

However, if you create a service or console application on the side, you may wind up with dependencies and perhaps crucial business logic in that service. And if you discover that you need access to singletons or other data in your web-application, you are stuck.

So what I do is to create a generic handler (.ashx) that calls into my services as usual. It's part of the web project. Then the scheduling of calling this handler a completely different task. Creating a windows service that simply just do a a simple http get on my handler is trivial and unlikely to change.